# vagrant+centos6にmysqlをインストールするとエラーが出る

Tags: mysql, centos, vagrant

すみません、初心者です。vagrant+centos6にmysqlをインストールすると以下の通りエラーが出るのですが、どなたか解決方法をご教示いただけないでしょうか？

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm -Uvh http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm を取得中
警告: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.5Iv17p: ヘッダ V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
準備中...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:mysql57-community-relea########################################### [100%]
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-server mysql-utilities
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror
インストール処理の設定をしています
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: www.ftp.ne.jp
 * epel: mirror.premi.st
 * extras: www.ftp.ne.jp
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
パッケージ mysql は mysql-community-client によって不要になりました。代わりに mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 のインストールを試みています。
パッケージ mysql-devel は mysql-community-devel によって不要になりました。代わりに mysql-community-devel-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 のインストールを試みています。
パッケージ mysql-server は mysql-community-server によって不要になりました。代わりに mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 のインストールを試みています。
依存性の解決をしています
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: mysql-community-libs(x86-64) >= 5.7.9 のパッケージ: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-devel.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be インストール
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: mysql-community-common(x86-64) = 5.7.19-1.el7 のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: systemd のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: systemd のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libnuma.so.1(libnuma_1.2)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libnuma.so.1(libnuma_1.1)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libnuma.so.1()(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-utilities.noarch 0:1.6.5-1.el7 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: python(abi) = 2.7 のパッケージ: mysql-utilities-1.6.5-1.el7.noarch
--> 依存性の処理をしています: mysql-connector-python >= 2.0.0 のパッケージ: mysql-utilities-1.6.5-1.el7.noarch
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> Package mysql-community-client.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-common.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be インストール
---> Package mysql-community-libs.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-community-server.x86_64 0:5.7.19-1.el7 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: systemd のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: systemd のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性の処理をしています: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit) のパッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-connector-python.x86_64 0:2.1.7-1.el7 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: python(abi) = 2.7 のパッケージ: mysql-connector-python-2.1.7-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package mysql-utilities.noarch 0:1.6.5-1.el7 will be インストール
--> 依存性の処理をしています: python(abi) = 2.7 のパッケージ: mysql-utilities-1.6.5-1.el7.noarch
---> Package numactl.x86_64 0:2.0.9-2.el6 will be インストール
--> 依存性解決を終了しました。
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
             要求: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
             要求: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-utilities-1.6.5-1.el7.noarch (mysql-tools-community)
             要求: python(abi) = 2.7
            インストール: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (@base)
                python(abi) = 2.6
            利用可能: python34-3.4.5-2.el6.i686 (epel)
                python(abi) = 3.4
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-connector-python-2.1.7-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql-connectors-community)
             要求: python(abi) = 2.7
            インストール: python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (@base)
                python(abi) = 2.6
            利用可能: python34-3.4.5-2.el6.i686 (epel)
                python(abi) = 3.4
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
             要求: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-client-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
             要求: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
             要求: libsasl2.so.3()(64bit)
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
             要求: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
エラー: パッケージ: mysql-community-server-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64 (mysql57-community)
             要求: systemd
 問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができません
 これらを試行できます: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: クリーンアップ、ありがとうございます。失礼しました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/89947

Answer (score 1):

既に解決されているようですが rpm の依存関係のチェックで弾かれています。
rpm パッケージは他のrpmパッケージに依存している場合があります。
依存先のパッケージを先に（もしくは同時に）インストールする必要があります。

mysql-community-libs-5.7.19-1.el7.x86_64が依存しているパッケージは次のコマンドで確認することができます。

```
# rpm -qpR mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
```

でもNGでしたが、

```
yum -y install mysql-server
```

でやってみたら、インストールできました。

とにかく、
http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
へのアクセスを拒まれている感じでした。

Comment: ブラウザから`https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm`にアクセスすると分かりますが元々ファイルが存在しません。正しくは`https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm`になります。